# Can type constructors be aliased in the same way as types?

Tags: f#

Consider the following:

```
module Module1 =

  type Foo = Bar | Baz

  type Lorem = {Ipsum: int}

module Module2 =

  type Foo = Module1.Foo
  type Lorem = Module1.Lorem

  let foo = Bar // Error: The value or constructor 'Bar' is not defined

  let lorem = {Ipsum = 2} // Error: The record label 'Ipsum' is not defined
```

Is it possible to alias the types in a simple manner and still be able to actually construct them, without opening `Module1`?

**Background:** I am creating an app and a corresponding web API. They will talk to each other by serializing and deserializing POCOs (POFOs?) whose definition is available in a module (corresponding to `Module1`) in a project referenced by both the app and the web API. The API and the types are versioned, so I'd like to have a `Types` module (corresponding to `Module2`) in the app and web API where I simply alias the most recent versions of the API types (e.g. `type Foo = Shared.V2.Foo`), and then I use these aliases inside the app and API, because that means I don't need references to the specific version all over the app/API. (Please shoot me if this is a terrible idea.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your type aliases are completely unused in your existing code. This works if you use them explicitly by qualifying those identifiers like this:

```
let foo = Foo.Bar

let lorem = {Lorem.Ipsum = 2}
```

Comment: I see, thanks. It seems the usage is similar to how it would be if the type was defined normally and decorated with `RequireQualifiedAccess`. Is this correct? And is there any way to use them without having to qualify them everywhere?

Comment: I wouldn't say it's like using `RequireQualifiedAccess`. In `Module1`, `Foo` is a type and `Bar` is a value created implicitly by the type declaration. In `Module2`, `Bar` just doesn't exist. There is nothing to connect it to the `Module2.Foo` type alias.